# Excel 2010 Pivot table Grouping by days of week

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Hi I am trying to group days of weeks for my pivot table, but because they appear in multiple times a week. I am unsure of which format to use in order to get my pivot table to work.

My data looks like this
[Mainsheet-Frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVUac.jpg)

and my pivot table when generated looks like this
[pivottable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfj4.jpg)

I am hoping that they will appear in days of weeks instead of coming out as individual.

Comment: Since single rows of data correspond to *multiple* days, grouping by days would end up duplicating results. Certainly you don't want that...correct?

Comment: That's what I want! I am looking to sum up SWU for every time it appears on the day of week.

Answer (score 0):

*To group the data by Weekdays, you can set 7 days Date from Monday to Sunday as

 weekdays.*

**Do the  following steps.**

1. Right click any Date in the Pivot table, & select Group from the Menu.
2. In Auto section, type the Start Date of the Week, if isn’t the First Day of it's week  as per your Date List then change the Date which is the First Day of the week beginning from Monday. The End Date needn’t to modify.
3. **Keep the Start Date Check Box, UN-Checked.**
4. Choose Days from the 'By list box' and enter 7 to 'Number of days box'.
5. Finish with OK.

*Hope this help you.*